# How do I show that a composite function of two homomorphisms is also a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question below seems to be transitive, but I have no idea how to connect G to G". 
**Show that if G, G', and G" are groups, and if phi maps from G to G' and gamma maps from G' to G", and both are homomorphisms, then show that the composite map phi gamma maps from G to G" is a homomorphism**.

Comment: What was your definition of homomorphism?

Comment: A transformation of one set into another that preserves in the second set the relations between elements of the first. The problem doesn't define the function.

Comment: So basically you're asking, if we know that $\gamma(xy)=\gamma(x)\gamma(y)$ for all $x$ and $y,$ and we know that $\phi(uv)=\phi(u)\phi(v)$ for all $u$ and $v,$ how can we prove that $\phi(\gamma(xy))=\phi(\gamma(x))\phi(\gamma(y))$? I wish I could help you with that, but it's been a long time since I took group theory.

Answer (score 3):

The following assumes $G,G'$ and $G''$ are groups, but a similar proof holds for other types of homomorphisms.

We want to show that $\gamma \circ \phi$ is a homomorphism, that is:

$(\gamma\circ\phi)(xy) = [(\gamma\circ\phi)(x)][(\gamma\circ\phi)(y)]$, or, equivalently, that:

$\gamma(\phi(xy)) = [\gamma(\phi(x))][\gamma(\phi(y))]$, for any $x,y \in G$.

(I am using the convention that $\gamma\circ\phi$ means first perform $\phi$, then subsequently $\gamma$).

Note that this equality holds in $G''$.

Now, since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, we have:

$\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$ (this equality takes place in $G'$). To keep the notation simple, let's use $x' = \phi(x)$, and $y' = \phi(y)$.

Since $\gamma$ is a homomorphism, we have: $\gamma(x'y') = \gamma(x')\gamma(y')$.

So...$\gamma(\phi(xy)) = \gamma(\phi(x)\phi(y)) = \gamma(x'y') = \gamma(x')\gamma(y') = [\gamma(\phi(x))][\gamma(\phi(y))]$, as desired.

Comment: Okay, so you work from right to left naming and substituting. I think I understand. Thank you.